# Why is the tomcat-users.xml getting ignored?

Tags: apache-tomee

Windows 7 TomEE-plume 1.7.4 (local)
Fedora 23 TomEE-Plume 1.7.4 (remote)
Firefox 46

http://localhost:8080 
http://192.168.0.100 (remote on Fedora 23)

The Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/7.0.68 (1.7.4) page comes up fine on both local and remote instances.

I have done my due diligence reading TomEE documentation and internet searches.
On the local Windows instance when any of the following buttons are clicked the browser goes directly to the page.  But on the remote instance of TomEE pressing the same buttons causes a small sign-on dialog to popup.  There is only one user id in the tomcat-users.xml file.  When the userid and password are used access is denied.  It was my understanding the Fedora id used to run TomEE-plume should be configured as "nologin".

Question 1) Am I correct in saying that the Fedora id used to run TomEE-plume should be configured as "nologin".
Question 2) Why won't the id in tomcat-users.xml work?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<tomcat-users>
<!--
  NOTE:  By default, no user is included in the "manager-gui" role required
  to operate the "/manager/html" web application.  If you wish to use this app,
  you must define such a user - the username and password are arbitrary.
-->
<!--
  NOTE:  The sample user and role entries below are wrapped in a comment
  and thus are ignored when reading this file. Do not forget to remove
  <!.. ..> that surrounds them.
-->

<!--
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
-->
  <!-- Activate those lines to get access to TomEE GUI -->
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <role rolename="manager-status"/>
  <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
  <user username="tomee" password="mypassword" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-status,manager-jmx" />
</tomcat-users>
```

Comment: It seems the  tomcat-users.xml file is only loaded on startup.  Once recycled all worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just repeating the answer here that you already know, that way this question doesn't come up as having no answer. No need to select this as the correct answer.

`tomcat-users.xml` is indeed only read at startup, you must bounce the JVM in order to pickup changes. If you want to be able to add/remove users on the fly, or change their roles without restarting the JVM, consider using an LDAP backed security repository. You can do this via the directions here: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html#JNDIRealm